# Magento 2 Catalog search results are not correct?

Tags: database, search, catalogsearch, magento2.3.2, search-result

I have migrated data from magento 1 to magento 2.

I am searching product name: `4.0ct Round Morganite Diamond Engagement Ring Bridal Set 14k White Gold` then it is showing lots of products on result page and searches product is not first. it is showing after many products.

When I have changed `search_request.xml` file and changed the `clause="must"` instead of `"Should"` in the XML.

Now, product is showing in autosuggestion but there is no results on the page.

If I removed number from starting of product name i.e. `ct Round Morganite Diamond Engagement Ring Bridal Set 14k White Gold`

The product is showing now on result page if I removed number from the starting of name

If I am searching product via SKU, it is working fine.

As I have checked, this issue only in migrated site. It is working in default magento 2.3